# Как обратиться к элементам Activity через Java-код?

Tags: activity, android, java

Как в Java можно обратиться к элементу `Activity` по его `android:id` и присвоить значение одному из его свойств?

Например как по `android:id=@+id/TableRow01` задать `style="@android:color/background_dark"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TableRow row = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.TableRow01);
row.setBackgroundColor(0);
```

этот код установит черный фон для TableRow 
К сожалению, применить в коде именно стиль нельзя. по крайней мере я нашел только такие высказывания.

Comment: Description Resource Path Location Type
TableRow cannot be resolved to a type MainActivity.java /PaperPlanes/src/dlp/app/content/paperplanes/free line 9 Java Problem